# MUI Autocomplete options and inputValue with Formik is Not Editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am Trying to create a form with reactjs, formik and MUI, but there is an Autocomplete in the form that i can't handle the problem is

when i give inputvalue then the it will not b editable so i cant see the other options or delete or type any letter

the form is data of the user which comes from API from Parent component that i Want to Update

here is an example of what i tring
and i have tried many ways too

can anyone help please???

```
            <Autocomplete                  
              name="doctor.speciality"
              options={specialities}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
              inputValue={formik.values.doctor?.speciality || ""}
              onChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                if (newInputValue) {
                  formik.setFieldValue(
                    "doctor.speciality",
                    newInputValue.value
                  );
                } else {
                  formik.setFieldValue("doctor.speciality", "");
                }
              }}
              id={formik.values.doctor.id}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  error={
                    formik.touched.doctor?.speciality &&
                    Boolean(formik.errors.doctor?.speciality)
                  }
                  onBlur={() =>
                    formik.setFieldTouched("doctor.speciality", true)
                  }
                  label="Speciality"
                  variant="filled"
                />
              )}
            />
```

Comment: I guess you need value prop instead of inputValue

Comment: then it doesnt show the default value, it will be empty

Comment: What version of mui autocomplete you are using? Is it possible for you to create sandbox and replicate the issue?